# How to store physical file location of files in MYSQL for a java EE web application?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

I have three projects in eclipse for a cloud web application where the user can login and should be able to store files.

**Front end**(servlets/html/jsp),

**Middleware**(ejb's),

**Backend**(MYSQL server)

There is already a working login form connected to the database that authenticates users.

From my understanding, BLOB is not advised and i should be storing the physical file location instead. 
I need to store the following information about each file:

- **file-name**,
- **file-type**,
- **physical-file-location**,
- **webcloud-location**

Ideally the user should be able to have access to other users directories if given permission.

So is that achieved in the same manner as implementing a login table that holds user credentials?

How exactly can a user download a file if the database only stores the location of the file?

Answer (score 1):

**Where to store.**

You are indeed correct that it's advisable to store merely the file location in the database instead of the file itself. The usual practice is to use a unique hashed name when storing the file in the cloud while saving both the unique hash and the original file name in the database.

**Sharing**

In web applications, user directories aren't the same as user directories on linux. In a web app, they are virtual. What you need is a sharing table  that links file ids with user id or group ids.

**How to download**

This is simply a matter of giving a link to the file as stored on the web cloud. If you have used a hashed name as mentioned above the file name is not guessable by others + you avoid the hassle of writing long lines of code to fetch the file from the cloud to the servlet container and pass through it's content to the user.